# How to show a different page action icon for each URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a simple extension to show an icon on different URLs.

My background script includes:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(o,r,m){for(var c=[
"URL1",
"URL2",
],a=0;a<c.length;a++)if(~m.url.indexOf(c[a])){chrome.pageAction.show(o);break}});
```

I would like to display a different page action icon for each of the two URLs. How should I proceed?

Comment: Please format your code for readability.

Comment: Please: Use variable names descriptive of what they represent. They cost you only a few characters, but significantly improve readability/maintainability. Suggest: use code blocks `{}` to indicate loops and/or conditional statements, particularly with a conditional as the only statement in a loop. Perhaps: [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of current loop. Using a Bitwise NOT `~` can have unintended consequences (vs. other comparisons or logical NOT `!`). Usually, **coding is not a contest to use the fewest bytes.**

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be looking for [`chrome.pageAction.setIcon()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setIcon).

I have re-written the code to be a bit more readable.  I changed your use of Bitwise NOT, `~`, to a test for `!== -1`. I used [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to both loop through the `urlList` (a new Object containing both URLs and the icons) and to indicate if a match was found so that the page action icon could be hidden if the URL does not match. I assumed you wanted it hidden on a non-match, given that you were `.show()`ing it when there was a match.

```js
var urlList=[{
    url:"URL1",
    icon:"/URL1icon.png"
},
{
    url:"URL2",
    icon:"/URL2icon.png"
}];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    if(!urlList.some(function(urlInfo){
        if(tab.url.indexOf(urlInfo.url) !== -1) {
            //The urlInfo.url must match the beginning of the tab's current URL.
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
            chrome.pageAction.setIcon(tabId,{
                path:urlInfo.icon
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })) {
        //Hide the icon if the URL does not match.
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
});
```